# Find all DropDown where a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have a very simple structure as shown below. what I am trying to do in jquery is find all dropdowns where the checkbox  is checked.

```
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDurationHours" runat="server"/> <td>
     <td>Data<td>
     <td>Data<td>
     <td> <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkDelete"/> </td>
     <td>Data<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddDurationHours" runat="server"/> </td>
     <td>Data<td>
     <td>Data<td>
     <td>  <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkDelete"/> </td>
     <td>Data<td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I have tried  few things can't remember them all but my latest attempt is:

```
var hoursDropdowns = jQuery('select[name*="ddDurationHours"]').closest('tr').find('td:first input[name*="chkDelete"]:checked:enabled');
```

Has anyone got a clue as I am banging my head trying to work this out.

Comment: same ID for both DropDownLists and CheckBoxes?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I simplified the output. It’s in a asp repeater, as asp.net changes the ID’s of the dropdowns . all I want is a list of all dropdowns where the name contains ddDurationHours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class selector for both dropdown and checkbox for much cleaner selector

```
$(".checkboxclass:checked").closet('tr').find('.dropdownclass')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('select[name*=ddDurationHours]').each(function(){

var len = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name*=chkDelete]:checked').length;
if(len == 1)
{
    var drd = $(this);
}

});
```

If checkbox is checked then you got length = 1, and you got your dropdown by $(this).

Answer (score 0):

This might be more easily achievable if you give one of the containing elements a class.

e.g.

```
<tr class="findme">
 <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDurationHours" runat="server"/> <td>
 <td>Data<td>
 <td>Data<td>
 <td> <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkDelete"/> </td>
 <td>Data<td>
</tr>
```

Then use:-

```
$('.findme input:checked')
```

To grab checked inputs in your structures.

You could also give a class to the CheckBox, but I'm fairly sure that when rendering a checkbox, ASP .NET wraps it in a span, so:-

`$('input.findme:checked')` might not work because the class is applied to the span, not the input.

Answer (score 0):

> $("input:checkbox:checked").parent().parent().find("select")